# Codrops Thumbnail Grid reload data?

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have implemented the [Codrops Expanding Preview](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/) script on a clients site. Everything is working great with the exception of one small glitch myself and team cannot figure out. We were able to customize the button text and add a new button ("Read Story" became LinkedIn which utilizes the href="" + we added Twitter which utilizes tag=""). Everything works well if you go from one item on the right and open another item on the left, but if you expand a preview on the left without a Twitter link and expand a preview on the right with a Twitter link - it saves the data from the previous expanded preview and does not show the Twitter link on the newly expanded preview because the other item did not have a Twitter link.

Here's the line of code showing the tag being utilized:

```
<a href="linked in url here" tag="#" data-largesrc="image url here" data-title="name here" data-description="description here ">
```

The tag="#" uses a # when there is no Twitter link.

In grid.js, we have added this to look for the # in the tag and have it display:none; -

```
if((eldata.tag).indexOf('#') >= 0) {
this.$tag.attr( 'style', 'display:none;' );
} else { this.$tag.attr( 'href', eldata.tag);
}
```

It seems to hold that value across all expanded previews and doesn't reload the data.

Is there any type of work around for this?